# Сдвиг метки на карте при масштабировании

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Метка на карте при масштабировании не остается на месте, ее начинает сдвигать, если уменьшить масштаб то метка указана не корректно, ничего подобного по теме не нашел, используются карты Apple, Google, Yandex. Проблема присутствует на всех.

```
- (YMKAnnotationView *)mapView:(YMKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<YMKAnnotation>)anAnnotation {
if ([[appSettings valueForKey:CAR_MAP_TYPE_KEY] integerValue] == MAPTypeYandex) {
    static NSString *identefier = @"pointAnotation";
    YMKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (YMKPinAnnotationView *)[aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identefier]; 
    if (!pinView) {
        pinView = [[YMKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:anAnnotation reuseIdentifier:identefier];
    }       
    if (![anAnnotation.title isEqualToString:@"current_location"]) {
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location_pin"];
        pinView.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location_pin"];
    }

    pinView.annotation = anAnnotation;
    pinView.canShowCallout = NO;
    pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(pinView.calloutOffset.x, 20);
    return pinView;
} else {
    if (![anAnnotation.title isEqualToString:@"current_location"]) {
        UIView *pinView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"location_pin"]];

        DXAnnotationView *annotationView = (DXAnnotationView *)[_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([DXAnnotationView class])];
        if (!annotationView) {
            annotationView = [[DXAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)anAnnotation
                                                          reuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([DXAnnotationView class])
                                                                  pinView:pinView
                                                              calloutView:[self createCalloutView]
                                                                 settings:[DXAnnotationSettings defaultSettings]];
        }
        return (YMKAnnotationView *)annotationView;
    } else {
        static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

        if (!pinView)
        {
            pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                        initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)anAnnotation
                        reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

            [pinView setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen];
            pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
            pinView.canShowCallout = NO;
        } else {
            pinView.annotation = (id <MKAnnotation>)anAnnotation;
        }

        return (YMKAnnotationView *)pinView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: код какой то можно посмотреть?

Comment: можно, но там его очень много, что именно нужно из кода???такое впечатление, что привязка идет не к нужной точке, а к центру, я читал для  JavaScript  есть свойство iconImageOffset, т.е. точка привязки иконки к карте, но для ios  ничего похожего найти не могу, может возможно вам известно похожее свойство для ios?

Comment: предполагая, что метка у вас создана при помощи MKAnnotation/MKAnnotationView там не так много кода.

Comment: Добавил код, посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в том, что я использовал свою собственную метку, и по умолчанию ее центр находился по центру этого image. По этому я использовал property которая есть у кастомной метки centerOffset, и подобрал координаты по x и y, чтоб картинка острым краем попадала в нужную точку. Вот строчка из кода:

```
pinView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, pinView.frame.size.height/4);
```

Спасибо